# How can I find the IPython output line by line in Spyder IDE?

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

My Python code is giving output properly, but it is not showing IPython code line by line as in Jupyter notebook. For example

```
import pandas as pd
```

When running this I get no output but a blank line.

Comment: Why would you want outputs from simply importing a module?

Comment: Do you want to see the code that is being run, or the output produced by each line?  `import ...` doesn't produce any output.  Try that in a `ipython` console.